# What is the difference between a statement, clause, and command in SQL?

Tags: sql

These terms seem to be used interchangeably. For example if I search SELECT on google, it will show up as a statement, clause, or even command. Is there any distinction between these terms that can help a beginner into SQL? I am just asking for the general SQL standard. I do know someone did ask about the difference between clause and statement, but even then some people mentioned how his answer was not a definite answer.

Comment: I think there are more important things to worry about! Generally, anything that is a complete runnable *thing* for a SQL environment would be called a Satement, It could be DML, DDL, etc. But equally you might refer to it as a Command, and I dont think there is any rule about this. A Clause is something that modifies the statement, like a where, join, exists, or anything else that forms part of a statement.

Comment: You use clauses to build up a complete statement.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, there is a difference.  The following is in the context of querying.

Three common SQL *statements* are `SELECT`, `UPDATE`, and `DELETE`.  A statement is a complete piece of code that can run independently.

A statement consists of clauses.  So, for a `SELECT`, common clauses are `SELECT`, `FROM`, `WHERE`, `GROUP BY`, `HAVING`, and `ORDER BY`.  Note that "clause" is also used for certain syntactic elements, such as the `WHEN` clause in a `CASE` expression.  This could be clarified as "subclause" or "expression clause", although I don't see that terminology.

A command is not usually associated with queries.  Instead, it more likely refers to the  scripting language -- which usually come with the database.  Often "statement" and "command" are interchangeable.  Note that "command" can also be used for a command line interface to the database.  It has more of a "programming language" suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Overall, clauses are used to filter or define conditions, functions perform specific operations on data, and statements provide the overall structure and organization for performing actions on a database. By utilizing these components together, SQL analysts can effectively query databases and retrieve the desired information.

Answer (score 0):

Statement is instructions or set of instructions which a server understands and executes to give an output

While clause is a part of statement which on its can't be executed but when combined with other clauses it's execution is possible.

For ex. If we take a sample select statement like

```
Select col1,col2,col3
From table_name
Where (some condition)
```

Here entire instruction is called statement but there are 3 clauses here

1. Select clause consisting of `Select col1,col2,col3`
2. Similarly from table_name is a clause
3. where is a clause.

These 3 independently can't be executed to give a output so they are clause.

Combining them into 1 and they can be executed so the combination is called statement

Answer (score -1):

Statement -  A raw sql query can be called as statement or sql statement.

Clause - A filter condition in sql statement can be known as clause like as where filter in sql statement can be called where clause in sql statement.

Command - Sql query executes in programming language via command function like as sqlcommand is a class in c# used to execute sql query or sql Statement .

Comment: Sometimes the different "words" are called commands as well: `update` command, `select` command.